# MongoDB Explicit Client-side Field Encryption for Dictionary type field

Tags: c#, mongodb, encryption

The basic document schema we are using resembles

```json
{
  "_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "usage": {
    "2024-01-01": {
      "param01": 123,
      "param02": 456
    },
    "2024-01-02": {
      "param01": 789,
      "param02": 147
    }
  }
}
```

We require the `usage` field to be encrypted.

Using the `MongoDB.Driver` to encrypt the field directly fails as there is no conversion available to the `BsonValue` base class passed into `ClientEncryption.Encrypt` from `Dictionary<>`.

The current solution uses an intermediate serialisation of `usage` to JSON prior to encryption.

```cs
var encryptedUsage = _clientEncryption.Encrypt(
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(usageData.Usage),
        new EncryptOptions(algorithm: "AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_512-Random", keyId: _dataEncryptionKeyId));
```

Is there a more elegant solution that would enable a Dictionary<> to be encrypted  and decrypted without an inline JSON intermediate step?

Could an implicit operator be utilised to take the Dictionary<> or a custom class and convert it to a type derived from `BsonValue`?

Could the same be done to facilitate a strongly typed document for the auto-decryption when reading?

We have little experience in this area and are unsure of the available options.

Answer (score 0):

With some experimentation, the use of `implicit operator` provided an acceptable solution.

The `usage` field in the persisted document was defined in C# with a class derived from `Dictionary<>`.

```cs
public class UsageReportModel
{
    [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy)]
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Identity { get; set; }
    public UsageCollection Usage { get; set; } = []
}
```

The new class then contains two operators that convert the class to and from BsonValue.

```cs
public class UsageCollection : Dictionary<string, UsageEntry>
{
    public static implicit operator BsonValue(UsageCollection usage)
    {
        return usage.ToBsonDocument();
    }

    public static implicit operator UsageCollection?(BsonValue usage)
    {
        var usageDocument = usage.AsBsonDocument;
        return BsonSerializer.Deserialize<UsageCollection>(usageDocument);
    }
}
```

The encryption is then

```cs
var encryptedUsage = _clientEncryption.Encrypt(
   usageData.Usage,
   new EncryptOptions(algorithm: "AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_512-Random", keyId: _dataEncryptionKeyId));
```

with automatic decryption supported

```cs
var usageReport = await usageReportCollection.Find(filter).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
var usage = usageReport.GetValue("Usage"),
```